# Limit of curvilinear integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $I(R)=\int_{\gamma_R}(1+x_1^2+x_2^2)^{-1/2}\cos(x_2)ds$, where $\gamma_R=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1^2+x_2^2=R^2,x_1>0\}$. Compute $\lim_{R \to +\infty}$$I(R)$. I tried to solve it in this way: I use parameterization $x_1=R\cos\phi, x_2=R\sin\phi, \phi \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and I get: \begin{equation} I(R)=\frac{R}{(1+R^2)^{1/2}}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(R\sin\phi)d\phi
=\frac{2R}{(1+R^2)^{1/2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(R\sin\phi)d\phi   \end{equation}
Now for $R \to +\infty$ :
\begin{equation}\frac{2R}{(1+R^2)^{1/2}}\sim2 \end{equation}
How could I study the integral to conclude the exercise?

Comment: Minor nitpick, the integrand should be $\cos(R\sin\phi)$. The usual techniques for this sort of limit are to either repeatedly apply integration by parts to get however many factors of $\frac{1}{R}$ you need, or use a substitution to move the location of the $R$

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the text.

Answer (score 1):

$|\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(R\sin\phi)d\phi|=|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(Rt)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt|=|\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}dx|\leqslant\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}|\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{R-x}}dx|$=$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}|\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos(R-t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}|\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos{R}\cos{t}+\sin{R}\sin{t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt|\leqslant\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}\left(|\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos{t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt|+|\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\sin{t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt|\right)$

$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos{t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\sin{t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$;

$$|\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(R\sin\phi)d\phi|\leqslant\frac{Const}{\sqrt{R}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In your last integral, let $\phi = \arcsin t.$ You will then have an integral of the form $\int_0^1 f(t)\cos(Rt)\,dt.$ Think about the Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: Interesting! But it is not a result that I know...